# How to deal with a regex which has any of its start and/or end split up over two lines?

Tags: java, regex, newline

Got a situation where the regex I built is working fine as long as the start and end sequences are onto one line and not fragmented. As an example if there is the need to extract the content from the following text between the ABCDE and VWXYZ sequences it should return `1234567890@#$@#$@##`:

```
-@$@$@#@$@AB
CDE123456789
0@#$@#$@##VW
XYZ00000
```

In the two instances ABCDE is different. I am hoping there is a way to cater for this in Java.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like there can be whitespace between `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` and `E`, right? Try `String pat = "(?s)A\\s*B\\s*C\\s*D\\s*E(.*?)V\\s*W\\s*X\\s*Y\\s*Z"`

Comment: The problem is not white space but when a newline gets into any of the sequences. So ABCDE could be A\nBCDE or AB\nCDE etc.

Comment: You know that you could always convert the string to a single line string right?

Comment: So, replace `\\s*` with `\n*`. `String pat = "(?s)A\n*B\n*C\n*D\n*E(.*?)V\n*W\n*X\n*Y\n*Z"`. Or with `\R*` (safer): `String pat = "(?s)A\\R*B\\R*C\\R*D\\R*E(.*?)V\\R*W\\R*X\\R*Y\\R*Z"` (as `\R` matches any line break).

Comment: Not working either Wiktor. This the implementation in Java that I am using:

Pattern patternToCheck= Pattern.compile(""(?s)A\\R*B\\R*C\\R*D\\R*E(.*?)V\\R*W\\R*X\\R*Y\\R*Z");

Comment: Rakesh, the data to scan will me quite big, more than 4Gb :(

Comment: I get it working - look at https://ideone.com/qdLjpl

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String pat = "(?s)A\\R*B\\R*C\\R*D\\R*E(.*?)V\\R*W\\R*X\\R*Y\\R*Z"` where `\\R*` matches zero or more linebreaks, and `(?s)` makes the dot in `.*?` match zero or more characters (including a newline) as few as possible (due to `*?` lazy quantifier).

See [this IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/qdLjpl):

```
String pat = "(?s)A\\R*B\\R*C\\R*D\\R*E(.*?)V\\R*W\\R*X\\R*Y\\R*Z";
String s = "-@$@$@#@$@AB\nCDE123456789\n0@#$@#$@##VW\nXYZ00000";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pat).matcher(s);
while(m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

If it works poorly, you may try another, unrolled regex but its performance will depend on how many `V` symbols there are in your content:

```
String pat = "A\\R*B\\R*C\\R*D\\R*E([^V]*(?:V(?!\\R*W\\R*X\\R*Y\\R*Z)[^V]*)*)V\\R*W\\R*X\\R*Y\\R*Z";
```

**In case you may have spaces there, in between letters**, use `\s*` instead of `\R*`:

```
String pat = "(?s)A\\s*B\\s*C\\s*D\\s*E(.*?)V\\s*W\\s*X\\s*Y\\s*Z"
// or
String pat = "A\\s*B\\s*C\\s*D\\s*E([^V]*(?:V(?!\\s*W\\s*X\\s*Y\\s*Z)[^V]*)*)V\\s*W\\s*X\\s*Y\\s*Z";
```

Comment: thanks Wiktor it works. If space is also included would need to add \\s after the \\R pls? If for example it is A B C D E not just ABCDE.

Comment: See my update. Just as I wrote in my first comment, use `\s` that matches *any* whitespace. If you have Unicode whitespaces, also add `(?U)` at the beginning of the pattern.

Comment: Replacing \R with \S is not working for some reason.

Comment: `\s`, not `\S`. `\s` is whitespace, `\S` is non-whitespace (the reverse shorthand character class)

Comment: Thank you Wiktor! Worked like a dream! Upvoted but still below 15 reputation.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer then. There is a grey tick mark under the up down arrows on the left.